# Make all menu items animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXmZ/) you can see how works one element of menu.

I'm stuck [applying this animation to all elements of menu](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXmZ/1/)

In theory it should work - I selected the hovered element by :

```
$('#menu').find('.category-holder');
```

and then begin applying animation to childs:

```
$(this).children().eq(0).delay(100).animate({opacity: '1'},400)
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I apply animation to all elements of menu?

Comment: one moment - confused the second link...

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: any ideas how to apply animation in fisrt fiddle - to all elements of menu in second fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out (first working "draft", some variable may be redundent):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.category-holder').hover(function (){
    // cache the parent menu element
    var menu = $(this).closest('.aMenu');
    var container = $(this);
    var containerFirstChild = $(this).children().first();
    var lettersArr = container.children();
    menu.data('pulsating',true);
    var numOfLetters = $(this).children().length;

    function pulse(){
      if(!menu.data('pulsating')) return;

        for (var i=0; i<numOfLetters ; i++) {
         lettersArr.eq(i).delay((i+1)*100).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
        }

      for (var i=0; i<numOfLetters ; i++) {
        if(i==numOfLetters-1){
                lettersArr.eq(i).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400,pulse);
        } else {
                lettersArr.eq(i).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
        }

      }
    }
    pulse();
  }, function(){
     // cache the parent menu element
     var menu = $(this).closest('.aMenu');

    $(this).animate({opacity: '0.5'}, 400);
      menu.data('pulsating',false);
  });
```

});

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXmZ/43/)**

I referenced various components using classes instead of id's and element types

Hope it helped.

Comment: +1. awesome. I was working on it right now. You absolutely right - there was problem with animation of quantity letters and it was solved perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Your $(this) in the pulse function is not what you think it is. It will only work in the outer hover statement. You can fix it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      $('#menu').find('.category-holder').hover(function (){
          var that = $(this);
        $('#menu').data('pulsating',true);
        function pulse(){
          if(!$('#menu').data('pulsating')) return;
          that.children().eq(0).delay(100).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          that.children().eq(1).delay(200).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          that.children().eq(2).delay(300).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          that.children().eq(3).delay(400).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          that.children().eq(4).delay(500).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          that.children().eq(5).delay(600).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          that.children().eq(6).delay(700).animate({opacity: '1'},400);

          that.children().eq(0).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          that.children().eq(1).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          that.children().eq(2).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          that.children().eq(3).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          that.children().eq(4).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          that.children().eq(5).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          that.children().eq(6).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400,pulse);
        }
        pulse();
      }, function(){
          $('#menu span:first').animate({opacity: '0.5'}, 400);
          $('#menu').data('pulsating',false);
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do more smart with for cicle, see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXmZ/2/).

```
var $target =   $('#menu span:first span');
for(var i = 0; i != $target.length; ++i) {
  $target.eq(i).delay(100 * (i + 1)).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
}
```

## edit

After your update, maybe you mean a stuff like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXmZ/45/).

more clean code, in my opinion.

Comment: @Velthune wow, it is much less accurate, I'm probably bad explain - I need to make all elements in menu whith this animation 

http://jsfiddle.net/6sXmZ/1/

Comment: I saw link before you update it.. btw is a good code! in a bit I post you an update

Comment: I updated my answer, by the way there're some error, but you can solve it easily